# API usage in all Communities

Tags: support, api

Is there a API to retrieve a general and specific question, answer and reply from different communities?

Comment: http://api.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an API.

Start here:

http://api.stackexchange.com/